# Recursive definition for $L = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid (a-b)$ is a multiple of 3 $\}$, and proving it's correctness.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Write a recursive definition for 
$$ L ::= \{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \mid   (a-b) \textrm{ is a multiple of 3 }\}$$**

I came up with this definition,

Base Case - $(0, 0) \in L $

Constructor Case - if $(a,b) \in L$ then, 
$$\begin{align*}
 (a+2, b-1) &\in L \tag{1.1} \\
 (a+1, b-2) &\in L \tag{1.2} \\
 (a+1, b+1) &\in L \tag{1.3} \\
 (-a, -b) &\in L \tag{1.4} 
\end{align*}
$$

The question follows with,

**Let $L'$ be the set defined by the recursive definition you gave for $L$ in the previous
    part. Now if you did it right, then $L' = L$, but maybe you made a mistake. So let’s check that you got the definition right. Prove by structural induction on your definition of $L'$ that**
        $$L' \subseteq L$$
**Proof-** **You can skip the proof and jump to the end where I ask my main question. If you would like to give some feedback on my proof technique please go ahead.**

The proof is by Structural Induction, on the definition of $L'$, the inductive hypothesis is
                    $$P((a, b)) ::= (a, b) \in L' \Rightarrow  ((a, b) \in L \Leftrightarrow 3 \mid (a-b))$$

- Base Case

  In the base case,  $$(a, b) = (0, 0) \in L'$$

Here, $a - b = 0 \Rightarrow (0, 0) \in L$ (as 3 divides $a-b$).

The base case holds as $P((0, 0))$ holds.

$$$$

**Inductive Hypothesis** - Let (a, b) be an arbitrary element of $L'$. Let $P((a,b))$ hold, that is $ 3\mid a-b $. We now prove that an element resulting from $(a, b)$ viz. $(a', b')$, satisfies $P((a', b'))$.

Constructor Cases: as by inductive hypothesis, $(a, b) \in L'$ then so does the following cases, by constructor case of the recursive definition,

- Case 1 : By constructor case (1.1), we have,
  $$(a', b') = (a+2, b-1) $$
  $$\text{For $(a', b')$ to be in L, $a'-b'$ must be divisible by 3}$$
   $$\begin{align} a' -b' &= a+2 -b +1 \\
  \tag{2} &= a-b+3 \end{align} $$
   from inductive hypothesis we know that 
  $$\begin{align} 
  3 \mid (a-b) &\Rightarrow 3 \mid (a-b+3)\\
  &\Rightarrow 3 \mid a' - b' \tag{from (2)} 
  \end{align}$$, which proves that in this case $P((a',b'))$ holds.
- Case 2 : By constructor case (1.2), we have,
  $$(a', b') = (a+1, b-2) $$
  $$\text{For $(a', b')$ to be in L, $a'-b'$ must be divisible by 3}$$
   $$\begin{align} a' -b' &= a+1 -b + 2 \\
   &= a-b+3 \end{align} $$
   from case 1 we know that when $a'-b' = a-b+3 \Rightarrow 3 \mid a' - b'$ 
   which proves that in this case $P((a',b'))$ holds.

  - Case 3: By constructor case (1.3), we have,
    $$(a', b') = (a+1, b+1) $$
    $$\text{For $(a', b')$ to be in L, $a'-b'$ must be divisible by 3}$$
    $$\begin{align} a'-b' &= a+1 -b -1 \\
    &= a-b \end{align} $$
    from inductive hypothesis we know that 
    $$\begin{align} 
    3 \mid (a-b)  
    \end{align}$$, which proves that in this case $P((a',b'))$ holds.
  - Case 4: By constructor case (1.4), we have,
    $$(a', b') = (-a, -b) $$
    $$\text{For $(a', b')$ to be in L, $a'-b'$ must be divisible by 3}$$
    $$\begin{align} a' -b' &= -a -(-b)\\
    &= -a+b = -(a-b)  \end{align} $$
    from inductive hypothesis we know that 
    $$\begin{align} 
    3 \mid (a-b) &\Rightarrow 3 \mid -(a-b)\\
    &\Rightarrow 3 \mid a' - b' 
    \end{align}$$, which proves that in this case $P((a',b'))$ holds.

As $P((a',b'))$ holds in all the constructor cases we can conclude that $P((a,b))$ holds for all values of $(a, b)$. 
$$$$
Or we can say if $(a,b) \in L' \text{ then } (a,b)\in L$ or $L' \subseteq L$.$\begin{align} &&\blacksquare \end{align}$

---

Now the question goes ahead with one more part which I can't solve,

- **Confirm that you got the definition right by proving that $L \subseteq L' $**

I have no idea how can I go from $(a,b)\in L $ to $(a, b) \in L'$. Should I search for an invariant that holds for all the constructor cases, I can't see any obvious invariant.

I would love to get some help as I am stuck on this problem since a couple of days.

Comment: Your work would be easier if the recursive definition you presented were cleaner: $(0,0)\in L'$ and for $((a,b)\neq(0,0)$, $(a,b) \in L'$ iff $|a|\geq|b| \wedge (|a|,|b|-3)\in L'$ or $|a|<|b| \wedge (|a|-3,|b|)\in L'$.

Comment: By this definition if $(a, b) \in L'$, then $3 \mid a \text{ and } 3 \mid b$, which is not what  the question is asking for, it is asking if  $(a, b) \in L'$ then  $3 \mid a-b$.